# How early to arrive for connecting flight at Munich airport?

Tags: air-travel, airports, munich, connecting-flights, oktoberfest

I have an 8-hour layover at Munich airport on September 16. I plan to go out to Munich city center. How early should I return for my connecting flight? The flight leaves at 15:35 and the luggage will be checked in from the first leg of the flight. The second flight is to the US, and I know I will need to pass through additional security check. I will also need to retrieve my hand luggage, which I will store at the left luggage facility.

Is getting at 13:30 enough? Also, it's the first day of Oktoberfest, so will I have any trouble getting to the airport with S-Bahn?

Comment: Which terminal are you flying from?

Comment: I'm flying with Lufthansa and I think all flights are from terminal 2.

Answer (score 1):

There should be no meaningful change in the S-Bahn schedule due to Oktoberfest, but lookout for any posted notices.

Exit controls and screening should take <30 min (my last experience was <10 min actually).  This will depend on any expedited queues you qualify for.

For clarity, there might be additional, but not necessarily separate checks.  I departed MUC right around all the recent hubbub and 'security' was only slightly more theatrical than usual, lots of swabbing and extra dower screeners.

You best be may be to just ask an airport official how long it takes to enter the terminal around 1330 and make plans from there.

Comment: Even if there are no scheduled changes to the S-Bahn, you must expect many more passengers travelling than on a regular Saturday and not unlikely some delays.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Does that mean I might miss a train or two?

Comment: @Giorgi I don't mean that the trains will be cancelled, but that the trains are not necessarily running reliably exactly at schedule and that the trip make take a bit longer than planned.

Comment: @Giorgi Oktoberfest = crowds and crowds = delays.  The trains will still run, but the to-the-minute schedule might suffer.  The airport line runs every ~20 min so it's not like you miss one and your stuck for an hour.  One of the DB apps might show live train data.

Comment: @Johns-305 By missing I meant that trains will be full because of more people coming to Munich